# Is there any error in this movabsq instruction?

Tags: assembly, att

```
movabsq $0x1F, %r9
```

This is an ATT version instruction so `$0x1F` is sorce and `%r9` is dest.

I think this instruction is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  You could have just tried it by assembling it into an executable and single-stepping it in a debugger.  (Yes, that line by itself in a `.s` will work with `gcc -nostdlib -static foo.s`, to get that instruction as the first one executed in user-space where you can single-step it.  And then crash if you let it step farther, but that's fine.)

Comment: If you mean efficient, though, in terms of how to set R9 = 0x1F, it's worse code-size than `mov $0x1F, %r9d`.  So it's correct but not efficient.